# How to use correctly the method nx.check_planarity of networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

**What I Want?**

I have a Graph with a lot of vertices and a lot of edges. The vertices are coordinated.
I am tring to check the planarity of the graph and I always get True as an answer.

**Exmple**

Here is a small exmple:

```
pos = {1: (0, 0), 2: (0, 1), 3: (1, 1), 4: (1, 0)}
    G = nx.Graph().to_undirected()
    G.add_nodes_from(pos)
    G.add_edge(1, 3, weight=1)
    G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=1)
    G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=1)
    print(nx.check_planarity(G, False))
    nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, pos=pos)
    plt.show()
```

the output is:

```
(True, <networkx.algorithms.planarity.PlanarEmbedding object at 0x07CD3E30>)
```

[image: Graph]

As you can see clearly the graph is not planarity, however the result is still `True`

**What am I doing worng?**

Answer (score 1):

Note that a graph is planar if it can be drawn in the Euclidean plane without any edge intersections.
In your case your graph is planar, as it is enough to swap nodes 1 and 4 to avoid edge intersections.
However, if you consider a complete graph (a complete graph `Kn` is planar only for `n ≤ 4`) you can see the difference.

```
>>> K4 = nx.complete_graph(4)
>>> nx.check_planarity(K4)
(True, <networkx.algorithms.planarity.PlanarEmbedding object at 0x1035df1d0>)
>>> K5 = nx.complete_graph(5)
>>> nx.check_planarity(K5)
(False, None)
```

Comment: So what is the best way to know if there are edge intersections in graph with coordinated nodes like in my example?

Comment: Even with the node position you have fixed, if for example you change the way edge (1,3) is drawn and make it curve, you are going to avoid edge intersections. Your problem thus seems to be different. You want to check if there is the intersection of any two edges given the fixed nodes positions and assuming the edges are drawn as straight lines. So it seems not to have much to do with planarity checks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the answer of check_planarity to draw a possible planar layout.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pos = {1: (0, 0), 2: (0, 1), 3: (1, 1), 4: (1, 0)}
G = nx.Graph().to_undirected()
G.add_nodes_from(pos)
G.add_edge(1, 3, weight=1)
G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=1)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=1)

is_planar, G2 = nx.check_planarity(G, False)
print(is_planar)

# plotting

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.margins(0.20)

# draws the graph as you have drawn it

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True, pos=pos)

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.margins(0.20)

# draws the graph without intersections => graph is planar because 
# it is possible to draw it without edge intersections

nx.draw_networkx(G2, with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```